# Auto login after successful signup in spring mvc

Tags: spring

I need to auto login after successful signup of user.I need to redirect the home page.but in my code it is not redirected to particular page.after signup it is still load the login page.

my signup controller:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController 
{
    @Inject 
    RequestCache requestCache;

    @Inject @Named("am")
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

     @RequestMapping(value = "/userCreate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public  String getuseradd( Model model, HttpServletRequest request) 
    {
        logger.debug("In getuseradd");
        logger.debug("User add "+request.getParameter("firstName"));
        String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
        String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        try{
            if(userService.searchRecords("Email", email).size()> 0)
            {
                return "redirect:/login";
            }
            else{
                Users user = new Users();

                user.setFirstName(firstName);
                user.setLastName(lastName);
                user.setUserStatus("Active");
                user.setEmail(email);
                user.setIsFacilitator(false);
                user.setPassword(password);
                user.setLanguageID(4L);
                userService.create(user, creatorID);
                Long userId = user.getUserID();
                UserRoleXREF userRoleXREF = new UserRoleXREF();
                userRoleXREF.setUserID(userId);
                userRoleXREF.setUserRoleID(4L);
                userRoleXREF.setComment(firstName);
                userRoleXREFService.create(userRoleXREF, creatorID);
                logger.debug("User role XREF created");
                authenticateUserAndSetSession(user, request);
            }
        }

        catch(AmmachiServerException ex)
        {

            logger.debug("AmmachiServerException: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return "redirect:/home";
    }
}
private void authenticateUserAndSetSession(Users user,
            HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        logger.debug("Authentication session"+user.getEmail()+""+user.getPassword());
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                user.getEmail(), user.getPassword());

        // generate session if one doesn't exist
        request.getSession();

        token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(request));
        Authentication authenticatedUser = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticatedUser);
    }
```

and my securitycontext.xml

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/userCreate" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/loginfailed" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <form-login login-page="/login" always-use-default-target="false" default-target-url="/home" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />

        <logout logout-success-url="/logout" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />


        <session-management>
            <concurrency-control max-sessions="10000" error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" />
        </session-management>


    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias = "am">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="loginValidator">
            <password-encoder hash="md5">
                <salt-source user-property="username"/>
            </password-encoder>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken is not authenticated, hence you are redirected to login page. 
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken constructor you called:

```
public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(Object principal, Object credentials) {
        super(null);
        this.principal = principal;
        this.credentials = credentials;
        setAuthenticated(false);
    }
```

You have to create a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken with an authorities list like so:

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), AuthorityUtils.NO_AUTHORITIES);
```

You don't use any roles in your security config so an empty authorities list is sufficient.

Now this UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken is authenticated:

```
public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(Object principal, Object credentials, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(authorities);
        this.principal = principal;
        this.credentials = credentials;
        super.setAuthenticated(true); // must use super, as we override
    }
```

You should be redirected to your home page.

AuthorityUtils is part of Spring security and can be found here `org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils`